# grails: can one war file serve 2 different domains?

Tags: grails

In the Config.groovy file there is the setting:

```
grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
```

Is there a way for a grails war file to be produced such that it can handle

```
    "http://www.site1.com"  and
    "http://www.site2.com"
```

?

Comment: remove `grails.serverURL` and use container configuration. Will break absolute links. So in this case you could use same war creating new instances on elasticbeanstalk (just an example)

Comment: Thanks Ivar.  The following link ( http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts#Configuring_Different_Webapps_for_Different_Virtual_Hosts.2C_But_at_the_Same_Context_Path )  for jetty explains how to configure multiple domains.  Do you know where this configuration file goes -- is it in the WAR file and if so do you know where?

Comment: ... is the first xml on the page starting with <Configure

Comment: If you refer to jetty then [jetty plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jetty) might help. I am not familiar with Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ivar's comment response:

remove grails.serverURL and use container configuration

This did work.   I happen to be running jetty 9.  In case you are too, there is an example test.xml file in the webapps.demo directory.   One can copy this in the webapps directory, rename it to the war name you are using, e.g. root.xml, and then just have a few entries in it:

- set the name of your war file, e.g. root.war
- fill in the virtualHosts area.